# Standalone app iOS size too large (218mb) with Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

Before starting, sorry for my English ! I’ll do my best !

I wanted to build my app for iOS, so, I used “exp build:ios” but that’s makes me an IPA too big ( > 200mb)
So I tried to detach my app to compile with ExpoKit, but that’s not a standalone app… That’s makes me an app whose connect to the expo server for launch my code ( and download it every time I launched it )

How should I build my app, and have it with better size ( around of 30mb )

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5):

> Hi! Your IPA contains [bitcode, as well as slicing for a few different
> device
> architectures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html),
> so it doesn't represent the final binary that will appear in the App
> Store.
>
> The Expo Client app, which is strictly larger than the code contained
> in your CRNA app, is currently 19.8 MB (compressed) in the App Store,
> and 26 MB when extracted onto a device. This varies slightly between
> versions as we update our SDK, but that's the ballpark figure.

https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-standalone-app-size-is-too-big

In addition to this, you may want to consider which assets you are bundling. By default every asset you use is bundled in the binary, but any of them can be downloaded on demand. You can go into `app.json` and remove the `assetBundlePatterns` key, then rebuild.

Read more at https://expo.fyi/managed-app-size

Comment: I've already saw this link, but I'm totally lost, should I use ExpoKit ?

Comment: Hi Raph, I think you should read my response more carefully. Using ExpoKit or not it doesn't matter.

Comment: My iOS managed expo app with a few screens, few pictures is 90 mb.. ouch. Android app is 46 mb.

Comment: @Hylle - as mentioned in the original comment, all you need to do is look at the Expo client app size to understand the size that your app can be - it will actually be a bit smaller because we only include on SDK version in standalone app builds, and we include 5-6 in the client. If your app is larger than that it's because you're not not factoring in bitcode or you are including lots of large assets.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong but a bare react-native cli version ended up being 9.8 mb on app store instead of 90 mb with Expo

Comment: probably you aren't including the same assets, I'd be happy to look at it if you post more info to forums.expo.io